# PowerShell script for creating collection along with database in each Azure Cosmos DB Account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I created the Azure Cosmos DB using ARM templates. But using the ARM templates you can’t create default collection along with database in the cosmos db.

I have multiple Cosmos DB Accounts, for each Azure Cosmos DB I want to create one collection with database also insert some dummy records into it.

So, can anyone suggest me how to write the PowerShell script for creating Default collection along with database in each Azure Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below powershell scripts to create collection with database in cosmos db :

```
$primaryKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '<your connectString>' -AsPlainText -Force
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account 'jaygongcosmos' -Database 'db' -Key $primaryKey
New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'MyNewCollection' -OfferThroughput 2500
```

About inserting dummy documents:

```
0..9 | Foreach-Object {
    $document = @"
{
    `"id`": `"$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())`",
    `"content`": `"Some string`",
    `"more`": `"Some other string`"
}
"@
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'MyNewCollection' -DocumentBody $document
}
```

More details,please refer to this [article](https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#working-with-collections).

---

For mutiple accounts,please use below code:

```
$array= '<your cosmos db account name>',.......
foreach($item in $array){

    $key = Get-CosmosDbAccountMasterKey -Name $item -ResourceGroupName 'jaygong'
    $cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $item -Key $key
    New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'Mytest1' -OfferThroughput 2500 -Database 'db'

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jay, Can you please update your answer with multiple cosmos DB accounts.

Comment: @pradeep Why not just loop the above ps scripts and pass the account name and key as parameters?

Comment: when I run the above script I am getting the error like `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\3.1.0.293\CosmosDB.psm1:5275 char:30`

Comment: This is the link for my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284155/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-at-c-program-files-window

Comment: @pradeep i noticed that your code misses `-Database 'db'` after the line `New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $collectionName -PartitionKey 'account' -OfferThroughput 50000` in your link.

Comment: @pradeep And I don't know why you unmark this case to create a new case for the new issue, even though I provided working code here.

Comment: @Joy, Whenever I am trying to insert the dummy I am getting error like `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\3.1.0.293\CosmosDB.psm1`