# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\3.1.0.293\CosmosDB.psm1

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a PowerShell script for creating database and collection inside Azure Cosmos DB. I am trying to insert some dummy records inside collection by using the below PowerShell script.

```
    #region Parameters

$clientId= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$clientSecret= "XXXXXXXXXXXX="
$subscriptionName= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$tenantId= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$resourceGroupName= "Demo"
$connectionString='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx=='
$cosmosDBAccounts= @('demo-account-01')
$databaseName='demo-db-01'
$collectionName='demo-collection-01'
$partitionkey= 'demo'

#endregion

#region Login into Azure using Interactive Mode or Service Principal details

# sign in
Write-Host "Logging in...";

#Connect-AzAccount 
$securePassword = $clientSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $clientId, $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId

#Set the current azure subscription
Select-AzSubscription  -subscription $subscriptionName

#endregion

#region Create Collection and insert some data into it

foreach($cosmosDBAccount in $cosmosDBAccounts){

    $key = Get-CosmosDbAccountMasterKey -Name $cosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDBAccount -Key $key
    New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $databaseName
    New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $collectionName -PartitionKey $partitionkey -OfferThroughput 2500 -Database $databaseName
0..9 | Foreach-Object {

$document = @"
{
         "id": "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())",
         "name": "pradeep",         
         "demo": "AAA"  
}
"@
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $collectionName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "AAA"

}
}



#endregion
```

But whenever I run the above script, I am getting the error like shown in below:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CosmosDB\3.1.0.293\CosmosDB.psm1:5275 char:30
>   + ...        $requestResult = Invoke-WebRequest @invokeWebRequestParameters
>   +                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Can you please highlight the line number where you are getting errors?

Comment: @Gaurav, I am getting error at this line  `New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $collectionName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey $partitionkey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the collection with the `$partitionkey= 'demo'`, so you need to new the document with it, then it will work fine.

```
 $document = @"
{
         "id": "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())",
         "name": "pradeep",         
         "demo": "AAA"  
}
"@
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'cll3' -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "AAA"
```

[image]

**Update**:

Try the complete command as below, it should work.

```
$cosmosDBAccounts= @('joycosmos')
$resourceGroupName = 'joywebapp'
$partitionkey = 'demo'
$databaseName = 'db1'
$collectionName = 'clle'

foreach($cosmosDBAccount in $cosmosDBAccounts){

    $cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDbAccount -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName    
    New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $databaseName
    New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $collectionName -PartitionKey $partitionkey -OfferThroughput 2500 -Database $databaseName

0..9 | Foreach-Object {

$document = @"
{
         "id": "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())",
         "name": "pradeep",         
         "demo": "AAA"  
}
"@

New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $collectionName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "AAA"

}
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting same error,Even I updated my script with your above answer.

Comment: @pradeep Try my updated command, may be due to your `$partitionkey` is global, just specific the `-PartitionKey "AAA"` directly, also dont forget to replace the `-CollectionId`.

Comment: Please look at my updated question. still I am getting same error.

Comment: Is there any possibility to insert the data from file which contains json formatted data.

Comment: @pradeep I am not sure, you could ask the specific question in another post.